# What is meant by frequency = 0?

Tags: terminology, probability, statistics

When I say that an event has frequency =0, does that imply that the event is impossible?

Comment: Unless I misunderstand the question, it seems to me it only means that the event does not repeat itself, i.e.,the event happens only once.

Comment: Are you talking about statistical frequency or motion frequency?

Comment: most of the answers seem to think your question is about oscillation frequency. If it is about statistical frequency then frequency zero means the event never happens.

Comment: The responses to this question about statistical frequency are a beautiful demonstration of physicists' obsession with harmonic motion :-D

Answer (score 1):

we say that an event is repeating  if the same event occurs again . Happening once doesn't mean that the event is repeating and frequency tells us the number of repetition in one second. So $0$ frequency means that the event doesn't repeated i.e. it had occurred only once .

Answer (score 1):

zero frequency means basically a constant term, no wave, no peaks passing you ever. Notice that the "wave" would have infinite period and wavelength, the time between peaks become infinite.

Answer (score 1):

Other answers have covered what the term "frequency" means in terms of waves or oscillations, but it is also a statistical term that describes how often an event occurs. A histogram, for example, often plots the frequencies of different events - it shows the number of times an event occurred. An event that was observed with a frequency of zero does not necessarily imply that the event is impossible, but merely that it was not observed in your sample. If you flip a coin once, and see that the frequency of heads is 1 and the frequency of tails is 0, that does not imply that tails is an impossible outcome. It *may* be an impossible outcome (if the coin actually has two heads), but there's no way to tell if an event is truly impossible or just unlikely when looking at a frequency of 0 in a finite sampling.

Even if we use "frequency" to describe the true, underlying probability of an event, a frequency or probability of zero still does not always imply an impossible event. Such an event may occur "almost never", but it is not actually impossible. Consider the event of randomly choosing the value 0.5 from the uniform distribution on [0, 1]. Since there are infinitely many real numbers in that interval, the chance of picking *exactly* 0.5 is zero. This event occurs with frequency/probability zero, but it is, in fact, a possible outcome.

Answer (score 0):

Zero frequency means no motion.

This makes sense because when we are talking about motion with a frequency $\omega$ we mean a position function like
$$x(t) = A \cos(\omega t) + B \sin(\omega t)$$

When you plug $\omega = 0$ into this you get
$$x(t) = A\cos(0) + B\sin(0) = A$$
which is just a constant position.

Answer (score 0):

> When I say that an event has frequency =0, does that imply that the event is impossible?

No, it does not.

Simple example: Suppose you have found that $x(t) = a + b\cos(\omega t + \phi)$ does a very nice job of describing some phenomenon, where $a$, $b$, and $\omega$ are non-zero. Another way of writing this is $x(t) = a \cos(0 \cdot t) + b\cos(\omega t + \phi)$.

The constant component `a` represents the zero frequency response.